# Using local NPM dependencies in the PATH - is there a tool that does this?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there an NPM package/tool that can (automatically) add local NPM packages to the $PATH?

This would represent a local development env that was independent of other projects.

NVM allows us to switch Node.js versions, but that doesn't seem to be enough to create an independent development space for each project. By By putting the locally installed command line tools on the $PATH, and giving precedence to local NPM dependencies, this would allow for us to change their versions without affecting any other project.

Comment: Your own command line tools or those installed by NPM?

Comment: If you open a terminal, the tool would automatically add `./node_modules/.bin` to the $PATH, or something like that.

Comment: when you `cd` out of the directory, it might have to remove that from the $PATH...so I think hooking into `cd` might be an important feature.

Answer (score 0):

NPX does this, which is bundled with NPM:
https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b

However, NPX looks like it does far too much.

I just wanted a simple tool that only adds the local executables to the path, if you are within an NPM project, so I wrote GMX:

https://github.com/ORESoftware/gmx